# Understanding average_degree_connectivity in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

I have some hard time to understand this graph quantity: [networkx.algorithms.assortativity.average_degree_connectivity](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.assortativity.average_degree_connectivity.html?highlight=average_degree_connectivity)

[image]

`average_neighbor_degree` returns a node id and its average_neighbor_degree:

> d – A dictionary keyed by node with average neighbors degree value.

However, I can't understand what `average_degree_connectivity` is? It returns:

> d – A dictionary keyed by degree k with the value of average connectivity.

For example, for three graphs the `average_degree_connectivity` vs. `average neighbors degree value.` look as follows. What does `average neighbors degree value.` mean?
[image]

1. What does `average_degree_connectivity` represent?
2. How is [`average_neighbor_degree`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.assortativity.average_neighbor_degree.html?highlight=average_neighbor_degree#networkx.algorithms.assortativity.average_neighbor_degree) related to `average_degree_connectivity`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes sense to answer your questions the other way round:

- Let `v` be a vertex with `m` neighbors. The `average_neighbor_degree` of `v` is simply the sum of its neighbors' degrees divided by `m`.
- For the `average_degree_connectivity`, this is the important part of the definition:

  > ... is the average nearest neighbor degree *of nodes with degree k*

  So for all the different degrees that occur in the graph, it gives the average of the `average_neighbor_degree` of all nodes with the same degree. It is a measure of how connected nodes with certain degrees are.

That are many averages, I hope this snippet clarifies question 2:

```
import networkx as nx
from collections import defaultdict

G = nx.karate_club_graph()
avg_neigh_degrees = nx.algorithms.assortativity.average_neighbor_degree(G)
deg_to_avg_neighbor_degrees = defaultdict(list)
for node, degree in nx.degree(G):
    deg_to_avg_neighbor_degrees[degree].append(avg_neigh_degrees[node])

# this is the same as nx.algorithms.assortativity.average_degree_connectivity(G)
avg_degree_connectivity = {degree: sum(vals)/len(vals) for degree, vals in
                           deg_to_avg_neighbor_degrees.items()}
```